# How to get Wi-Fi on Ubuntu with secure boot enabled?

Tags: networking, 18.04, realtek-wireless, secure-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 along side windows 10 on HP desktop. The Wi-Fi of the system works well on windows 10 , but on Ubuntu 18.04 it shows no wi-fi adaptor found. After going through internet I was able to get Wi-Fi on Ubuntu **but for this I have to disable secure boot from BIOS settings. Is there any way to get Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 18.04 with secure boot enabled?**
Desktop have Realtek drivers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/a/769840/167115)

Comment: Yes. I believe this [particular answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769840/167115) is the one you need. If you need help with the path to your module or module name, just let us know or respond to this with @mchid at the beginning of the comment so that I will get a notification of your response.

Comment: Although, I believe you may be able to trust or sign the driver through your "software and updates" application settings and/or "additional drivers" which can both be found where you search for installed applications. I'm having trouble finding an example but I believe you have to reboot with secure boot disabled, trust the module or driver through your software and updates or additional drivers app while secure boot is disabled. then you should be able to reboot with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Additionally, please edit your question and provide the source you used for the driver and they type of card you have. This will help other people quickly identify a solution if they know of one. Thanks.